# How to change chef nginx default http port 80?

Tags: apache, nginx, chef-infra

I tried to install apache on a machine that chef-server was installed. Apache could not start up due to the occupation of port 80 by chef nginx. If I want to let apache use port 80 as default, is it possible to change chef nginx default http port to another one?

I found a solution on the Internet to set virtual host on both apache and nginx, but they need a [different FQDN](https://serverfault.com/questions/679184/sharing-chef-server-with-apache) as server name. My machine uses an IP instead of FQDN, so I need to change the default HTTP port for chef nginx.

I tried to add `/etc/chef-server/chef-server.rb` with the following content:

```
nginx['non_ssl_port'] = 9898
```

Then I ran 'chef-server-ctl reconfigure'. It didn't work.

Can anyone help on this? Thanks.

**Updated**

My information was wrong regarding changing the chef server settings.

The settings should be added into `/etc/opscode/chef-server.rb` for Chef12. After `chef-server-ctl reconfigure`, nginx's HTTP port is changed to 9898.
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds strange as it should have worked. I've exactly the same configuration on my chef-server.rb and it works. Maybe try a `chef-server-ctl restart nginx`. (you should be able to ensure what is used by reading `/etc/chef-server/chef-server-running.json`

Comment: It worked after running `chef-server-ctl restart nginx`. nginx no longer occupies port 80, but it doesn't seem to listen new port 9898. When I `knife client list`, I got the error `ERROR: Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect`. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Depends on your knife.rb content, does `the chef_server_url` start with https ? I suspect you now go to apache and it redirects to apache ssl port, not chef one.

Comment: Yes. My `chef_server_url` is `https://ip/organizations/xxx`. 1) If I still want to use ssl, how should I redirect request to chef nginx? 2) If I disable ssl, should `chef_server_url` be changed to `http://ip:9898/organizations/xxx`? Thanks.

Comment: I suspect something else, does `chef-server-ctl status` shows all services running ? (before any other modification I would ensure all is ok server side) Maybe the fight for port 80 has left it unstable, try a `chef-server-ctl restart`, another  `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` and a last restart if all is not started to get all the services up and running. (`chef-server-ctl  tail` could help see the errors too). Sounds like we will need a chat room for this :p

Comment: bookself, nginx, oc_bifrost, oc_id, opscode-erchef, opscode-expander, opscode-expander-reindexer, opscode-solr4, postgresql, rabbitmq, rdis_lb are running after `chef-server-ctl restart`. They seem to work well.

Comment: Let's continue this on chat [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75266/chef) instead of flooding comments :p

Comment: Sorry. I don't have enough reputation to talk in chat room. I can enter the chat room but cannot type anything.

Comment: Can we find another chat room? Or....skype?

Comment: irc.freenode.net on #chef channel would help (I tried adding you as allowed on the room, but even that does not work :/)

Comment: Can we use google chat? My gmail is `talihsu`. I cannot open irc.freenode.net.

Comment: I upvoted your questions so you now have 20 rep, the SO chat should be available (but you may have to leave and rejoin the chat room)

Comment: I can see I have 20 rep in my profile, but `You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.` still shows on the bottom of the chat room. :(

Comment: In webchat.freenode.net.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how to change the port. Edit `/etc/opscode/chef-server.rb`

```
nginx['non_ssl_port'] = 10080
nginx['ssl_port'] = 10443
nginx['url'] = "https://<YOUR URL>:10443/"
```

and adjust your local `~/.chef/knife.rb` to read

```
chef_server_url 'https://<YOUR URL>:10443/organizations/<YOUR ORG>'
```

But currently there is a bug in Chef that prevents the embedded nginx to run on a non standard port: https://github.com/chef/chef-server/issues/50

Answer (score 1):

The settings should be added into `/etc/opscode/chef-server.rb` for Chef12.

After `chef-server-ctl reconfigure`, nginx's HTTP port is changed to 9898.