# Install Lets Encrypt on Chef Server

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, lets-encrypt

I want to install a Letsencrypt certificate on my Chef server. I followed [this guide](https://www.tienle.com/2016/06-08/install-chef-server-lets-encrypt.html):

```
git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt
cd letsencrypt
./letsencrypt-auto
./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone --email your-email@email-service.com -d chefserver.DOMAIN.com
```

But this leads to `Problem binding to port 80: Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6.`, so I had to change the configuration that my server allows traffic on port 80. Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30592653/1405981) I created `/etc/opscode/chef-server.rb`:

```
nginx['non_ssl_port'] = 80
nginx['ssl_port'] = 443
nginx['enable_non_ssl'] = true
nginx['x_forwarded_proto'] = 'http'
nginx['url'] = 'http://chef.mydomain.com'
```

After running `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` I found out that `/etc/opscode/chef-server-running.json` has been changed.

But the server still redirects my http-traffic to https, so a Letsencrypt certificate still can't be generated.

How can I get a Letsencrypt certificate for my Chef Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The --standalone flag you tried initially spawns certbot's own server on port 80. This failed because you had something else listening on port 80. If that is your chef server, one option is either disable it listening on port 80 (maybe stop the server temporarily) or move its non_ssl_port to some other port, i.e. 8000.

If it's not the chef server listening on port 80, you should investigate what it is (i.e., it could be an instance of nginx or apache server).

After you find out and release port 80, then your initial set of commands should work and produce the certificate.

Comment: I killed all chef related processes and restarted letsencrypt. A dirty workaround, but the best I could get.